# What does "High time you forget things and move on" mean?

Tags: sentence-meaning

I received a message from someone that says:

> High time you forget things and move on.

What message does she want to pass on to me?

Comment: This really needs more context, esp. what are the "things"? "move on" is idiomatic and could have several meanings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'High time' means it is the time you must act on something. Here, she wants to say that you really need to forget things.

'Move on' in such context is keep going without sticking to one thing.

So, simply put, forget things now and focus on your own goals or start living in routine life without being affected by those things that bother you.